# Aptana 3 - Setup PHP Executable

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to use an Aptana plugin that requires a PHP executable with a certain name. Everywhere online people just say to go to Window > Preferences > PHP > PHP Executables.

There is no "PHP Executables" menu in my Aptana 3 though.

Is there another way to setup PHP Executables in Aptana 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging/running, there is a way if you get the latest nightly build (preview.appcelerator.com/studio).

Once you are on the nightly, the debugger feature that includes the support for PHP executable will add this preference page under *Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > PHP > Debugger*